# Multiple word spelling correction

Tags: python, nlp, probability, spell-checking

Correcting one word spelling mistakes (both non-word & real-word mistakes) is easy:

```
P(w|c) P(c)
```

Where `w` is the incorrectly spelled word and `c` is the candidate we're trying to match, such that the candidate is a one word token.

But in Google, when you enter something like `spelligncheck`, it corrects the word into two different words. Now, `P(w|c)` is easy here, if i use levenshtein distance. But that means i can't have one word (one token, rather) candidates anymore. So this will increase the size of my dictionary exponentially.

Moreover when I enter `app le` Google corrects it to `apple`...

So what is the best way of doing multiple word spelling correction, given a one-token dictionary?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science.

Comment: so where do i ask it?

Comment: I don't see why it can't be asked here. Right now, there are 1,361 questions on SO explicitly tagged `computer-science`, many of which are of a similar algorithmic flavor.

Comment: Also, @AnshumanDwibhashi : to answer your question, think in terms of character language models instead of word language models. What appears to be two words in the latter (word LM), is simply a sequence of characters with an extra space in the character LM. So, instead of thinking in terms of P(w|c), think in terms of P(c_1 c_2 ... c_k | c).

Comment: @ChthonicProject okay, now i understand. so if i think in terms of character language models i can do multi-word spelling checking. How do i go about multi-word semantics (word-similarity)?

Comment: Semantics are much harder. Multi-word similarity essentially boils down to being able to handle paraphrasing ... it's an insanely difficult problem. There are some good research papers (just search for "paraphrase" in the [ACL anthology](http://aclweb.org/anthology/)), but beyond those papers, you will be in uncharted territory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the [`pspell`](http://www.php.net/pspell) module.

I've prepared this demo to show you how almost achieve what you want - it clearly could be improved a lot more:

```
<?php

class SpellChecker
{
    public function __construct($lang)
    {
        $this->pspell = pspell_new($lang);
    }

    public function check($word)
    {
        return pspell_check($this->pspell, $word);
    }

    public function closest_suggestion($word)
    {
        $suggestions = pspell_suggest($this->pspell, $word);
        $similar_sounding_words = array_filter($suggestions,
            function ($current_word) use ($word) {
                return (metaphone($current_word) == metaphone($word));
            });

        // No similar sounding words, just return the first suggestion...
        if (count($similar_sounding_words) == 0) {
            return $suggestions[0];
        }

        // Return the closest match against similar sounding words...
        return array_reduce($similar_sounding_words,
            function ($prev, $next) use ($word) {
                return (is_array($prev))
                    ? $next
                    : ((levenshtein($prev, $word) < levenshtein($next, $word))
                          ? $prev
                          : $next);
            });
    }
}

$spellchecker = new SpellChecker('en');

foreach (array('spelligncheck', 'app le') as $word) {
    if (!$spellchecker->check($word)) {
        print "Closest match for \"$word\": {$spellchecker->closest_suggestion($word)}\n";
    }
}
```

I've tried here and got the following result:

```
Closest match for "spelligncheck": spellchecker
Closest match for "app le": apple
```

Good luck! :)

Comment: it would be better in python.. but anyway. does this require my own corpus(hopefully) or PHP's own corpus?

Comment: list of words... and @PauloFreitas it doesn't solve all my criteria. spelligncheck should be spelling check.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi It uses the system-wide default pspell dictionary and let you combine with your own dictionary through [`pspell_config_personal()`](http://www.php.net/pspell_config_personal) function. You can even add words to your personal dictionary at runtime using [`pspell_add_to_personal()`](http://www.php.net/pspell_add_to_personal), and let you further save them to your custom dictionary with [`pspell_save_wordlist()`](http://www.php.net/pspell_save_wordlist). :)